# Libcurl - problema em utilizar função write/read propria

Tags: c, libcurl

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para um dispositivo embarcado e dentre as bibliotecas que tenho que usar é a [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), o problema que o dispositivo embarcado que estou usando não faz uso das funções de escrita e leitura padrões do C, exige o uso de funções proprietárias, fazendo assim que o [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) não funcione corretamente no dispositivo.

Procurei na documentação oficial e achei estas tags que podem ser configuradas pelo `curl_easy_setopt` :

- [CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION.html)
- [CURLOPT_READFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html)
- [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html)
- [CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.html)

Pelo que entendi, as tags citadas, permitem configurar o callback a ser chamado depois da execução das respectivas funções, não me permitindo alterar a forma de criar o `socket`, `write`, `read` e `close`.

Ou seja, como consigo configurar o [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) para executar estar funções proprietária?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os próprios desenvolvedores da biblioteca me responderam no github.

Link da resposta:
[GIHUB - Discussions](https://github.com/curl/curl/discussions/8712)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).